# Sitecore Azure Paas Media files not appearing

Tags: azure, paas

I have installed fresh new Sitecore Azure Paas (Sitecore 9 update 2). Created a Sitecore packages from my local to the new instance to migrate all the content, media, system and templates. Everything worked except media items. I have created media items packages from my local to new Azure instance. Installed the packages, Media items have been created but there is no media files attached to those items. All media items are showing as "no files has been attached".

Comment: Are your media items possibly file based? Check if the File Path field is filled out on your local instance.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain No, in my local instance its not file based. File path field is empty in all media items in my local instance.